# Converting a list of indices of a cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array, matrix-indexing

I have an array x:

```
x = [2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]
```

I also have a cell array y:

```
y = {'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'}
```

In fact, `x` is a list of indices, where each indicates an element in `y`. I now want to create another cell array `z`, where each index in `x` is replaced with the corresponding element in `y`, to give the following:

```
z = {'beta', 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'gamma', 'beta'}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

How about this :

```
z = y(x)
```

I do not have MatLab on my computer right now, but I think that should work.